# How to change file properties(Created By, Modified By etc.) while sending file as base64 in API Callout?

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, base64

I have integrated Microsoft OneDrive with Salesforce, now I have requirement of Creating a file (in base64 form) from Salesforce using POST callout in Microsoft OneDrive API.

But I want to change the file properties like Created by Name, Last Modified Name, Owner Name etc. while creating file from Salesforce using REST API.

Is there any way to change file properties before sending the file's base64 in API callout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to create the file on Salesforce or in OneDrive? How is this related to Salesforce?

Comment: I have integrate salesforce with One Drive and trying to do POST API callout to create a file in OneDrive from Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

The audit fields cannot be set. If you check the [DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource, you'll see these properties are read-only. For example:

> | Property | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | createdBy | identitySet | Identity of the user, device, and application which created the item. Read-only. |
> | ... | ... | ... |